# MS Access - VBA - OLE Object

Tags: vba, ms-access, ole

I saved some graphs as OLE Objects in one of my tables.

Now, I'm developing a word document using VBA from inside the MS Access; however, I do not know how to insert the OLE Objects saved in my table into the created word document.

Comment: Extract the objects to folder location then insert into Word document. These graphs are what type of file? Why use Word and not Access report? Is this a split db and backend is Access file? I never use OLEObject field.

Comment: Review https://lebans.com/oletodisk.htm